# OpenERP V7- New Button Customization

Tags: python, odoo

Im very new to OpenERP. Can anyone guide me how to create a button and when clicking on this button should popup the form to get and save record.

Answer (score 1):

Visit this https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/design_element/ and check the others attributes of button.